# Java Updater Game Launcher

Tags: java, launcher

I'm trying to make a Java game updater launcher for my game. Similar to how minecraft works. However, minecraft has only a few .jar's to download wheras I would need to redownload all of my game assets. Is there any easy way for Java to check a file for which operations need to be taken? One idea I had was using .7z files since those can be compressed really small. That wouldn't work though because I can't seem to get Java to hook onto 7zip operations. Another idea I had was if it determined if an update was needed it would read a file with a set of commands like this:
remove assets/models/malecharacter.obj
add assets/models/alien.obj
...etc

But I'm not sure this is very efficient and I am also not able to find a lot of help with managing files. Any help and ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You could split your bins up. From there, you can just do version checks on them. Unless you want to do bytecode manipulation, jar modification would be very hard. If you just do resource-bins (images, animation dumps and models) and modify those files it could work. Another thing you could try is a jar comparer to see what bytes change and where, then generate a series of modifications that must be needed such as: `at byte 184 replace the next 26 bytes with these 290 bytes: {list of bytes}`. Just some ideas you could try out.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But, what if my stuff is not in JAR's? I'm using the unity game engine to develop this game.

Comment: Isn't minecraft launched using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info)?  *"Is there any easy way for Java to check a file for which operations need to be taken?"*  Operations?  Beyond 'check for an updated file & download if available' what sort of 'operations'?

Comment: I used jars as an example, yet bin resources would be the same.

Comment: Andrew, I mean download this file, remove that file.

Comment: Legend, if I use bin resources I don't believe I can use them with unity.

Answer (score 1):

I made a Game Launcher in Java recently, I still have a few problems to solve like how to update the launcher itself.

Anyhow, for the game updates/versions I just have a "versions" folder with a folder for each downloaded version, it might not be the prettiest of solutions but it works for multiple versions and it's easy to make.

My launcher checks a URL from my dedicated server which has all available versions, which I call it versionlist, then since the versions folder on the server obeys a path order I can call any versions which are in the versionlist. I download the selected version and extract it to a separate version folder on the user's pc.